# Loading a xib file on several different UITableViewControllers issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib

I wonder if any of you guys ever encountered this problem. 
I have a xib table cell with UIImage, UILabel(s) and an UIButton. Pretty simple and straight forward.

The thing is, when I use this xib on different UITableViewControllers, the positioning of my elements are not the same. Any ideas?

Comment: put code of cellForRow of both tableViews

Comment: Is the tableview controller of different sizes? Are you working with autolayout enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Well,

1. Check your springs & struts or restraints to make sure that they are correct.
2. If still not working and you are using storyboards, give up this xib and arrange the storyboard directly. This will involve copy the UI over for multiple times.
3. Last resort, manual layout in `-[UITableViewCell layoutView]`.